# CakePHP 3.x Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm getting following error while formatting date in listing table data. Initially value of date is "0000-00-00 00:00:00" and it cause error.

```
 Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object.
```

Version: CakePHP 3.x

Table name: 'actions'

Fields & Record:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [action_name] => Call
    [show] => no
    [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)
```

Code :

```
    $this->loadModel('Actions');
    $query = $this->Actions->find('all');
    $row = $query->first();

    echo $row->created->format("F d, Y");
```

Value of $row:

```
Cake\ORM\Entity Object
(
    [_properties:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [action_name] => Call
            [show] => no
            [created] => 
        )
    ...

    ...
```

How to check blank value of date and avoid above error?

Comment: use `$query->hydrate(false)->first()` instead of `$query->first()` and then try `$this->Actions->format("F d, Y", $row['created'])` or may be `date("F d, Y", $row['created'])`

Comment: Getting error Unknown method "format" on using your solution.

Comment: You might be getting it on `$this->Actions->format`, use `date("F d, Y", $row['created'])`. Also it was a typo from my end. It could be `$this->Action->format` (without 's')

Comment: Still not working :: Unknown method "date"

Comment: can you paste your code. date is a php function. it should be used as it is. It should work. date() should not be called on any class. You can copy-paste `date("F d, Y", $row['created'])`

Comment: $row = $query->hydrate(false)->first();  echo $this->Actions->date("F d, Y", $row['created']); die;

Comment: It should be `$row = $query->hydrate(false)->first(); echo date("F d, Y", $row['created']); die;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93351/discussion-between-yogesh-suhagiya-and-ashish-choudhary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
$row = $query->first();
echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($row->created));
```

Answer (score 0):

First the error message:

```
Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object.
```

Too me, it also seems that `$row` is of type `Array` so you should access `created` with `$row['created']` insteadof `$row->created`.

`$row['created']` is a string, not an object. Which means, it does not have that `format` method you tried to call.

So, you could get desired result with:

```
echo date("F d, Y", $row->created);
```

Comment: $row is object of Entity class. I had updated my question by adding value of $row, pleas check it.